# Antlr4 grammar for a function with variadic argument list

Tags: c#, antlr4, grammar

I'm trying to write a grammar for a DSL of mine using antlr4. In essence I'm trying to create a DSL for describing function applications in a tree structure.

Currently, I'm failing at creating the correct grammar (or using the visitor in C# correctly) for parsing expressions like

```
#func1(jsonconfig)
#func1(jsonconfig, #func2(...))
#func1(#func2(...), #func3(...), ..., #func_n(...))
#func1(jsonconfig, #func2(...), #func3(...), ..., #func_n(...))
```

my grammar (with some parts removed for brevity)

```
func
    : FUNCTION_START IDENTIFIER LPAREN (config?) (argumentList?) RPAREN
    ;

argument
   : func
   ;

argumentList
   : (ARG_SEPARATOR argument)+
   | ARG_SEPARATOR? argument
   ;

config
   : json
   ;
```

however, when trying to parse an expression I'm getting only the first argument, not the rest.

this is my visitor:

```cs
public class DslVisitor : JustDslBaseVisitor<Instruction>
{
    public override Instruction VisitFunc(JustDslParser.FuncContext context)
    {
        var name = context.IDENTIFIER().GetText();

        var conf = context.config()?.GetText();
        var arguments = context.argumentList()?.argument() ?? Array.Empty<JustDslParser.ArgumentContext>();

        var instruction = new Instruction
        {
            Name = name,
            Config = conf == null ? null : JObject.Parse(conf),
            Bindings = arguments.Select(x => x.Accept(this)).ToList()
        };

        return instruction;
    }

    public override Instruction VisitArgument(JustDslParser.ArgumentContext context)
    {
        return context.func().Accept(this);
    }
}
```

I think there is probably some syntax error in the `antlr` definition because it fails to parse a list, but successfully parses a single item.
In the past I had a slightly different syntax, but it required me to always pass a config object which doesn't fit my needs.

Thanks!

Comment: If it's a parsing problem, please provide the input and enough of the grammar so we can reproduce the parse. We don't know any of the lexer rules.

Comment: I really think its a syntax issue, I'm adding a [github link](https://github.com/EugeneKrapivin/JsonTranslate.NET/blob/main/tests/JsonTranslate.NET.JustDsl.UnitTests/JustDslTests.cs#L46) to the failing test (which is currently ignored) if it helps because adding enough to reproduce will be quite long here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few problems.

First, you don't actually test the parse result in [your code](https://github.com/EugeneKrapivin/JsonTranslate.NET/blob/main/src/JsonTranslate.NET.Core.JustDsl/JustDslSerializer.cs#L39) after the parse. You should add an ErrorListener and test whether the lexer and/or parser actually found errors. You can also use that to shunt the output to where ever you like.

```
public class ErrorListener<S> : ConsoleErrorListener<S>
{
    public bool had_error;

    public override void SyntaxError(TextWriter output, IRecognizer recognizer, S offendingSymbol, int line,
        int col, string msg, RecognitionException e)
    {
        had_error = true;
        base.SyntaxError(output, recognizer, offendingSymbol, line, col, msg, e);
    }
}
```

Simply create a listener, call `AddErrorListener()` for parser, call parse method, then test `had_error` for the listener. Note, you should add a listener to the lexer as well.

Next. It took a lot of editing [this C# code](https://github.com/EugeneKrapivin/JsonTranslate.NET/blob/main/tests/JsonTranslate.NET.JustDsl.UnitTests/JustDslTests.cs#L52) to actually get the input that people expect. I removed the C# escapes and reformatted it to get this for the input:

```
#obj(
  #property(
    #unit(
      {"value":"phoneNumbers"}
    ),
    #agr_obj(
      #valueof(
    {"path":"$.phone_numbers"}
      ),
      #current(
    #valueof(
      {"path":"$.type"}
      ) ),
      #current(
    #valueof(
      {"path":"$.number"}
  ) ) ) ),
  #property(
    #unit(
      {"value":"addrs"}
    ),
    #agr_obj(
      #valueof(
    {"path":"$.addresses"}
      ),
      #current(
    #valueof(
      {"path":"$.type"}
      ) ),
      #current(
    #obj(
      #property(
        #unit(
          {"value":"city"}
        ),
        #valueof(
          {"path":"$.city"}
      ) ),
      #property(
        #unit(
          {"value":"country"}
        ),
        #valueof(
          {"path":"$.country"}
      ) ),
      #property(
        #unit(
          {"value":"street"}
        ),
        #str_join(
          {"separator":", "},
          #valueof(
        {"path":"$.street1"}
          ),
          #valueof(
        {"path":"$.street2"}
) ) ) ) ) ) ) )
```

Third. You don't augment your grammar with an entry rule that has EOF at the end of the rule. An EOF-augmented rule forces the parser to consume all the input. Here, I just added the rule for "start":

```
start : func EOF ;
```

You will need to change your entry point to `start()` rather than `func()`.

Finally, your grammar does not recognize a `json` arg followed by optional `func` arguments. Since the first arg for a `func` can either be `json` or `json , func` or `func`, you need to make an exception for the first arg. This grammar fixes that:

```
grammar JustDsl;

LPAREN:             '(';
RPAREN:             ')';
FUNCTION_START:     '#';
ARG_SEPARATOR:      ',';

IDENTIFIER
    : [a-zA-Z] [a-zA-Z\-_] *
    ;

start : func EOF ;

func
    : FUNCTION_START IDENTIFIER LPAREN argumentList? RPAREN
    ;

argument
   : func
   ;

argumentList
   : (config config_rest)?
   | no_config_rest?
   ;

config_rest
   : (ARG_SEPARATOR argument)*
   ;

no_config_rest
   : argument (ARG_SEPARATOR argument)*
   ;

config
   : json
   ;

json
   : value
   ;

obj
   : '{' pair (',' pair)* '}'
   | '{' '}'
   ;

pair
   : STRING ':' value
   ;

arr
   : '[' value (',' value)* ']'
   | '[' ']'
   ;

value
   : STRING
   | NUMBER
   | obj
   | arr
   | 'true'
   | 'false'
   | 'null'
   ;


STRING
   : '"' (ESC | SAFECODEPOINT)* '"'
   ;


fragment ESC
   : '\\' (["\\/bfnrt] | UNICODE)
   ;
fragment UNICODE
   : 'u' HEX HEX HEX HEX
   ;
fragment HEX
   : [0-9a-fA-F]
   ;
fragment SAFECODEPOINT
   : ~ ["\\\u0000-\u001F]
   ;


NUMBER
   : '-'? INT ('.' [0-9] +)? EXP?
   ;


fragment INT
   : '0' | [1-9] [0-9]*
   ;

// no leading zeros

fragment EXP
   : [Ee] [+\-]? INT
   ;

// \- since - means "range" inside [...]

WS
   : [ \t\n\r] + -> skip
   ;
```

Mike was on the right track (but had a typo with the `functionArgs` rule). But without the input, this problem was difficult to solve.

Comment: I didn't actually get to adding error listeners yet. I was working on getting the library functionally working before hitting some of the known bugs. I'll add it promptly though, thanks for the pro tip!

regarding the input formatting, this is a little of detour from the original question, just of curiosity, what would you think about files holding the fully formatted and unescaped inputs which the tests would read?

Comment: after your suggestion, while visiting the `func`, is there a reliable way to know which of the 2 options of `argumentList` was actually chosen? I'm not the idea I have of checking if `config != null` is the best course of action

Comment: I would like to thank you for your swift assistance and awesome explanation :)
Could I reference your GH handle in the issue close commit?

Comment: Glad to help. The formatting came in handy just to identify the problem with the parse. Otherwise, Antlr would just point to someplace in the middle of this huge string, and I'd have no idea what I was looking for. Whether you put that in a file or in a string in the unit test, no big difference. On understanding in the visitor which alt is used, you could add a label and that would redo the visitors that would be available to you. Take care with Antlr4cs, the old Antlr4 code for C#, with visitors. It's not the official Antlr4. See https://github.com/kaby76/Antlr4BuildTasks for replacement.

Comment: I've just found your repo, tried to shift my little code base to it.however I had some problems migrating to your solution with the `Antlr4.Runtime.Standard` nuget. Something I liked in the "official" antlr4 nuget is that I didn't have to get JREs and the JARs themselves.

Comment: "Official" nuget pkg is [Antlr4.Runtime.Standard](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4.Runtime.Standard/). [Antlr4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4/) and [Antlr4.Runtime](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Antlr4.Runtime/) nuget pkgs are [Harwell's forked copy](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs) from [official](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4), years behind. Antlr4BuildTasks is a direct replacement of Antlr4. You do not download any jars, Java JRE, set env vars. It's all there in the package. Example here https://github.com/kaby76/AntlrExamples/tree/master/ArithmeticAntlr4Std

Comment: (1) Every reference to Antlr4.Runtime, Antlr4.CodeGenerator, and Antlr4 4.6.6 everywhere has to be removed, e.g., especially [this](https://github.com/EugeneKrapivin/JsonTranslate.NET/blob/main/src/JsonTranslate.NET.Core.JustDsl/JsonTranslate.NET.Core.JustDsl.csproj#L24). (2) Simplify lines in the .csproj! `<ItemGroup><Antlr4 Include="JustDsl.g4" /></ItemGroup>`. You get the Visitor by default. (3) It should be Antlr4.Runtime.Standard 4.9.2 not 4.9.0; Antlr4BuildTasks 8.14, not 8.12. Seems to compile fine with these changes.

Comment: You are correct my dear sir :) I had my versions wrong and for some reason I carried over the Antlr4 dependency. Probably what threw me off-course. After the proposed changes all builds with green tests. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try something like:

```
func
    : FUNCTION_START IDENTIFIER LPAREN functionArgs RPAREN
    ;

functionArgs :
    : config (ARG_SEPARATOR argument)*
    | argument (ARG_SEPARATOR argument)*
    ;

argument
   : func
   ;

config
   : json
   ;
```

Alternatively (if you really want the `argumentList` node)

```
func
    : FUNCTION_START IDENTIFIER LPAREN functionArgs RPAREN
    ;

functionArgs :
    : config (ARG_SEPARATOR argumentList)?
    | argumentList
    ;

argumentList :
    : argument (ARG_SEPARATOR argument)*
    ;

argument
   : func
   ;

config
   : json
   ;
```